# Missing permissions required by FusedLocationClient

Tags: java, android, xml, syntax, permissions

I'm working on getting an app to get GPS location from a phone. I have added permissions to the XML for ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION but it is still saying that I need permissions for that, even though the permission is already in the XML.

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;


public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "Kindness";

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
                this);

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this,
                new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {

                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.byui.cit.kindness">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisison.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="edu.byui.cit.kindness.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: either go to setting and grant the permission of your app or prompt for a runtime permission.. from the user..

Comment: you are using marshmellow or above ryt ?

Comment: Just try with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION instead. I'm not sure how `getLastLocation()` works, but if the "last location" happens to be an accurate one from GPS, then of course you can't have it with the "coarse" permission. And of course in more recent Android versions you'll need to runtime permission as in pushasha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because location permissions [are considered "dangerous" permissions by Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), and when your application's target SDK is 23 or greater, you are required to ask for "dangerous" permissions at runtime. Just adding them to the manifest does not work.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful. I have some reading to do on permissions requests.